# Mark specific Django migrations as fake migrations during test DB setup

Tags: django

I have some database migrations, some are structural migrations some are data migrations

eg.

```
0001_initial.py
0002_import_data.py
0003_add_field.py
0004_import_more_data.py
```

I would like to skip those data migrations (0002 and 0004) as I don't want to spend the effort to fake the source for those data migrations but still run 0001 and 0003 when running `python manage.py test`

Is it possible?

Comment: Do those data migrations just move data? Your test DB won't contain any data so there shouldn't be anything to move?

Comment: @IainShelvington external data source, updated migration names to be more obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the data migration files and conditionally set `operations` to an empty list, or remove just the operations you want to skip. You then need to detect when you are running under a test, this can be done by having a separate settings file or setting an environment variable

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(import_function),
    ]

    if settings.TEST: # if os.environ('SKIP_DATA_MIGRATIONS') == 'true':
        operations = []
```

Comment: ah how come I never thought of it, good idea